# Using One-Time-Password in moodle

Tags: moodle, one-time-password

I am using moodle 2.x for some testing courses.

I'd like to use one-time-password for moodle login. 
That means when users login with certain password, then they can take exams in that session.
However if they close the window or login their account, they can't login again anymore. And if they want to continue to take another exam, the teacher or administrator will help them by provide another password or something like that help them to login again.

Thanks all,
Noat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you will have to write a new auth plugin or you can use

```
prelogout_hook()
```

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins#pre_loginpage_hook.28.29

to suspend the use account